# Error in reading video file in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, video, image-processing, matrix

Hi
 I am getting a strange error while trying to read a video, frame wise in matlab. I am doing the following:

```
xyloObj = VideoReader(vid_name);
fps = xyloObj.FrameRate;
nFrames = xyloObj.NumberOfFrames;
vidHeight = xyloObj.Height;
vidWidth = xyloObj.Width;

% Preallocate movie structure.
mov(1:nFrames) = ...
    struct('cdata', zeros(vidHeight, vidWidth, 3, 'uint8'),...
    'colormap', []);
index =1;
for k = 1:nFrames
    mov(index).cdata = read(xyloObj, k);
    index = index+1;
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using VideoReader/read (line 80)
The file could not be read.
```

Haven't found solution to this error anywhere else.
EDIT: File format is avi. something like: D:\videos\drunk.avi.

Comment: provide some information about the video, its format. You can paste the filename here with the entire path.

Comment: @Parag it's an AVI file. I am reading many files one by one. While it works on some files, for others I am getting this error.

Comment: Should that be `for k = 1:modified_nFrames` instead of `for k = 1:nFrames`?

Comment: @RogerRowland I am changing the fps. So I guess I had to do this. Is it incorrect?

Comment: Ok, must have misunderstood, just wondering if you sometimes try to read one too many frames. The array you read into has size `modified_nFrames`.

Comment: @RogerRowland even if I modify it to standard nFrames loop I am still getting the same error. So no I am not reading too many frames.

Comment: check the codec of the problematic files. Matlab does not support all AVI codecs.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a mmread? I used VideoReader on Linux, but in my case, the length of frames is not correct.

Moreover, since I need the timestamp of videos, I have changed from VideoReader mmread.